# How could I create new arrays with the modified max/min values for this Binary Search function

Tags: c++, binary-search

I am trying to implement a Binary search function, I was wondering how to modify the new arrays with new min/max values. Also I am new to C++ so could anyone tell me if this is a correct implementation of Binary Search? Thank you.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

bool doSearch(int arr, int target)
{
int min = 0;    
int max = arr.length() - 1;
while(min != max)
{
    int avg = (min + max)/2;        
    if(arr[avg] < taget){
        min = avg + 1
    }
    else if(arr[avg] > target){
        max = avg - 1;

    else if (arr[avg] == target)
        {
            return avg;
        }   
    }
}
return -1;
```

}

```
int main()
 {
int primes[]={2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47,53,61,67,71,73,79,83};
int result = doSearch( primes , 47 );
cout<<"Found prime at index " <<result;

}
```

Comment: Format your code. There are no semi colon in several lines.

Comment: I think you should get your code to compile first and then fix the implementation once you have some result you can iterate on. For starters, c++ does not support slicing of primitive array types, so you can't do something like `arr[min : max]`. Maybe look into the `std::array` class which provides some of the features you are trying to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> bool doSearch

If you want to return the index, then this should be

```
int doSearch
```

---

> doSearch(int arr, int target)

Should instead be something like

```
doSearch(int arr[], int size, int target)
```

Because in c++, there is no predefined function to get the length of an array. So your function would look like

`int doSearch(int arr[], int size, int target)`

---

> while(min != max)

Should be

```
while (min <= max)
```

Because, otherwise, the search will not return the index when the target is at index where min = max. i.e., consider the case of 
`int arr[] = {0};` and the function call `doSearch(arr, 1, 0);`.

---

For finding the size of the array, you can use

```
sizeof(primes) / sizeof(primes[0])
```

So your function call becomes

```
int size = sizeof(primes) / sizeof(primes[0]);
int result = doSearch(primes, size, 47);
```

Do note that you can't calculate the size like above inside the doSearch function, as arrays are passed as pointers to function.

---

Moreover, once inside `if (arr[avg] < target)` and `else if (arr[avg] > target)`, there is no need to check for the remaining conditions, so you can use continue to go to the next iteration of while loop i.e.,

```
if (arr[avg] < target)
{
    min = avg + 1;
    continue;
}
else if (arr[avg] > target)
{
    max = avg - 1;
    continue;
}
```

---

Finally, since your main is expecting an int as return you can `return 0` and before returning use `system("pause")`, so that the console window doesn't close as soon as it shows the result.

```
system("pause");
return 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the following changes.

- First change return type of doSearch from `bool` to `int`.
- Then add `;` in required places such as  `min = avg + 1;`
- Change your while loop condition to
  `while(min <= max)`
- Then change your code in main() to

  `if(result != -1)
      cout<<"Found prime at index "<<result;
  else 
      cout<<" Not found";`

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


template<size_t N>
int doSearch(int(&arr)[N], int target)
{
    int max = N - 1;
    int min = 0;
    int returnValue = -1;


    while (min <= max)
    {
        int avg = (min + max) / 2;
        if (arr[avg] < target) {
            min = avg + 1;
        }
        else if (arr[avg] > target) {
            max = avg - 1;
        }
        else if (arr[avg] == target)
        {
            return  avg;
        }

    }
    return returnValue;
}


int main()
{
    int primes[] = { 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97 };

    int result = doSearch(primes, 47);
    cout << "Found prime at index " << result<<endl;


    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

You had a handful of errors in your code - both syntax and logical. Your first mistake was the process through which you found the array length. I used a not so typical way to find the length - there are other ways to do so but I did it using templates because it's more fun. Also in your while loop you had it `while(min!=max)` this would never arrive at the answer since it would stop if the answer lies at a position where min and max are the same - for example your array. Also your original function was returning a bool - that did not make any sense since you are looking for the position which is an `int`. There might still be some errors in this code still. Please feel free to correct. I hope this helps!